# String to Object literal

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to convert a string var:

```
 data="data1,data2,data3,data4"
```

to an object literal

```
data={
"data1":"data2",
"data3":"data4"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really mean an object LITERAL? If so, then you just did it. A literal is something that a programmer types in when writing the source code.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why'd you accept @deceze's answer?

Comment: @Mark, were you just trying to be funny?

Comment: @Jacob, they both work, thank you, however deceze's answer appeared first on my screen. I do thank you though.

Comment: I'm not really trying to be funny, but trying to understand your question. The answer that you accepted generates an object, not an object literal. To generate an object literal, you'd have to download some code at http://www.json.org/js.html and use the JSON.stringify() method on the parsedData variable that @deceze's code produces...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var arr = data.split(',');
var parsedData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    parsedData[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: @Jacob Is there? Enlighten me.

Comment: @deceze In your code? Nope. But the votes, that's another story :P

Comment: @Jacob Somebody did though... :/

Comment: @deceze Yeah. I do find it funny though that we came up with relatively the same solution, and really really fast. :)

Comment: @Jacob There really aren't that many (sane) ways to do it... :)

Comment: @deceze So we're both insane then? :P

Comment: @Jacob Why else would we be here? :D

Answer (score 6):

This is trivial:

```
function object_from_string(str) {
   var parts = str.split(','),
       obj   = {};
   for(var i = 0, j = parts.length; i < j; i+=2;) {
       obj[parts[i]] = parts[i+1];
   }
   return obj;
}

var data = "data1,data2,data3,data4";
var obj = object_from_string(data);
for(var k in obj) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      console.log(k + ' = ' + obj[k]);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
data1 = data2
data3 = data4
```